# If push notification can be sent successfully on development device, why the app can't receive the push notification when installed ad-hoc?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm developing an app that uses push notification. When tested on development device (e.g. installed using cable connected to the Mac), it can receive push notification correctly. But when it's installed using ad-hoc means, no push notification received.

But, the app can obtain the device id on both development and ad hoc scenario. This is evident by the device id received and recorded on the server. The server receives device id on both development and ad hoc scenario. But even then, if the app is installed using ad hoc means, it's not receiving any push notification from the server.

PS:

- I'm using Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3.
- I have created the certificate using SSL push notification for distribution and development, and have included (double click) the certificate on the Xcode.
- I have made sure that the capabilities for push notification is ON. Both steps on push notification are also has ticks.
- I archived the app using Xcode automatically manage sign in. Xcode is supposed to linked in all the correct certificates for me, including the certificates for SSL push notification for distribution and development... right?

What is your thought on what's wrong with this, and the solution for this? Thanks.

EDIT:

When I tried to use manual code signing, here's what I got:

[image]

I can't resolve the status issue. I know that the debug is supposed to have different provisioning. But for now, that's not the main issue. If I can solve the status issue, I also can solve the different profile.

Comment: Did you tried to archive the app manually by choosing the correct certificate and provisioning?

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad I cannot archive the app manually, because apparently Xcode 8 is fussier than Xcode 7. Some of the old steps working for Xcode 7 isn't working in Xcode 8. For instance, when I choose my provisioning profile, it keeps saying that `"Provisioning profile <insert provisioning profile name here> doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: <insert team name here>"`. This never happens in Xcode 7, and I don't know how to solve this. Right now I'm creating archive manually using Xcode auto-generated profile `(XC iOS Adhoc <insert product bundle id here>)`. Wish me luck

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad it's still not working even with Xcode auto-generated profile.

Comment: check this image https://g32i.imgup.net/image39f4.png and make sure that your target config is like the image. Notice below items too: -- Make sure that you unchecked "automatically manage signing"  -- Make sure that you had downloaded the app certificate from you developer account and also added the certificate to your Mac keychain -- Make sure that you had downloaded the provisioning profile from your xcode Preferences->Accounts

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad I have updated the question with further information and screenshot of the same settings. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Have you got a deviceToken?

Comment: @Suen yes I have. Hence this question. I even able to send push notification from server to development device (app installed via cable). But I can't send push notification to the same app installed to the same device via adhoc means.

Comment: make sure that you have downloaded the development and distribution certificate of your app( from apple developer panel for your account) and added both of them to your key-chain. (please notice that you should add both of aps and app certificate for both distribution and development type to your keychain)(also please notice that the app certificate is the certificate that your provisioning profile includes it as its app certificate)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure if the certificates for the push notification in adhoc environment are created fine. Secondly, the UDID is getting saved on server properly or not.

Comment: "Making sure the certificates for adhoc is created fine" --> how to make sure of that? How to find out that it's not created correctly? But, "UDID is getting saved on server properly" --> this I can make sure, and it's saved properly.

Comment: When you pass push to the UDID from server, it gives you the log, can you share that log. From this point you will get to know about your certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check your uuid of mobile provision in ipa is correct by running command `security cms -D -i yourprovisionname.mobileprovision` in bash.

> the trailing lines 
>     <key>UUID</key> 
>     <string>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</string>

you can unzip your .ipa file and find embedded.mobileprovision in your Payload/App

If mobileprovision is correct, you should check your certifications.

Note that **The certification of production environment is different than sandbox.**

After checking the certification, you can check the server side. When we push to a sandbox(development), we push to address `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`, and in the distributed environment, we push to `gateway.push.apple.com`(no sandbox).